# ng2-translate on a component.ts file

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have the following code in home.component.ts file

```
notificationId.innerHTML = message
```

and the message is displayed as notification on the site.

How do i translate the message here and display the translated message on the site?

Tried this :

```
this.translate.instant(message)
notificationId.innerHTML = message
```

but this didn't help. I have the translation for all the corresponding messages in a json file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because to use `instant` method you have to be sure that `package` with language is loaded, otherwise it won't `translate`. The best option for getting translate inside component ts file is `get` method because you are subscribing to its value. So it would look like this:

```
this.translate.get(message).subscribe(translatedMsg => notificationId.innerHTML = translatedMsg);
```

However I would not recommend to use `innerHTML`. You should use two way binding in template. like `<div class="notification">{{notificationMessage}}</div>` and implement this variable in ts file. Also please check if you have are correctly loading language package in `app.module.ts`.